# How to activate giftcard account after creation in magento 2

Tags: coupon-codes, magento2-enterprise, gift-card, account

I can create a giftcard account as:

```
$model = $this->giftCAFactory->create()->setStatus(
            \Magento\GiftCardAccount\Model\Giftcardaccount::STATUS_DISABLED
        )->setWebsiteId(
            $this->_storeManager->getStore()->getId()
        )->setBalance(
            40
        )->setIsRedeemable(
            TRUE
        )->save();
```

**N.B:** I am creating with *`STATUS_DISABLED`*, if I create with *`STATUS_ENABLED`*, I can redeem that gift code as it is already activated in this case.

But I need to activate programmatically giftcard account after creation as we can do from backend:

[image]

I tried by loading `model` and setting status to `enabled` but it is not working as:

```
$model = $this->_objectManager->create(\Magento\GiftCardAccount\Model\Giftcardaccount::class);
                $model->load($id);
                $model->setStatus(
                \Magento\GiftCardAccount\Model\Giftcardaccount::STATUS_ENABLED
            );
```

Any help will be highly appreciated !!

Comment: above code is your full code or something is missing? because I can't see save function

Comment: @RakeshVarma I missed save();. It's working now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned by @Rakesh save() was missing, it works now:

```
$model = $this->_objectManager->create(\Magento\GiftCardAccount\Model\Giftcardaccount::class);
                $model->load($id);
                $model->setStatus(
                \Magento\GiftCardAccount\Model\Giftcardaccount::STATUS_ENABLED);
                $model->save();
```